# How to remove everything excluding what's between given characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am automating a task, where I need it to open a .csv or .txt file, that will have a bunch of information I don't need. I want to remove everything excluding what's in a specific range.

For example: `adhjnwadk'symbol:xxx'abcahjda`.

So I would want to keep everything in `'symbol:xxx'` and remove everything outside of it. Please note that xxx is a variable and is different in every line.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are the ‘ always at the start & end? If so get their positions with find() and then extract with mid().

Comment: Hi Mike, so how it will always look like is as follow Sym="xxx" so xxx is a variable, but " is what it always ends with

Answer (score 0):

Is this a dataset? If yes, then you can use pandas module in python to get the data in tabular format and segregate accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin this particular cat:

```py
with open("data.txt", "r") as infile:
    symbols = []
    for line in infile.readlines():
        _, _, lineend = line.partition("'symbol:")
        if lineend:
            symbol = lineend.split("'")[0]
            symbols.append(f"'symbol:{symbol}'")
```

This finds everything after `symbol:`, discards everything after the `'`, and stores the `'symbol:xxx'` in a list.

Comment: Hi Jack, This doesn't seem to be working, and it might be my fault. So the symbol is actually statused as Sym="xxx" I have changed the script as follows and it doesn't want to work

Comment: with open("data.txt", "r") as infile:
    symbols = []
    for line in infile.readlines():
        _, _, lineend = line.partition("Sym:'")
        if lineend:
            symbol = lineend.split('"')[0]
            symbols.append(f'Sym:"{symbol}"')

Comment: `"Sym:'"` - it looks like you have a `'` in the wrong place?

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for the quick reply. That I fixed already but still nothing please see : 

with open("log.txt", "r") as infile:
    symbols = []
    for line in infile.readlines():
        _, _, lineend = line.partition('Sym:"')
        if lineend:
            symbol = lineend.split('"')[0]
            symbols.append(f'Sym:"{symbol}"')

Comment: That has `partition('Sym:"')` and the `"` is in the wrong place :D

Comment: I gave another user some detailed help on `partition` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71112549/2449857) and this might help you too

Comment: So my question to partition('Sym:"') is that the file has the part i want to keep as Sym:"xyz" so is this still correct?

Comment: oh, yes, if your input string is actually `'correct horse Sym:"xyz" battery staple'` then the separator would be `'Sym:"'`, and `lineend` will be `'xyz" battery staple'`.

Comment: Yeah that's how I have it as above, and it's not working any ideas?

Comment: replace `_, _, lineend` with `linestart, separator, lineend` and print them out? If everything's in `linestart` then the separator's wrong. Otherwise `lineend` will show you what exactly you need to split on to get the `xyz`.

Comment: I tried this: Still nothing... with open("log.txt", "r") as infile:
    symbols = []
    for line in infile.readlines():
        linestart, seperator, lineend = line.partition('Sym:"')
        if lineend:
            symbol = lineend.split('"')[0]
            symbols.append(f'Sym:"{symbol}"')
print (linestart, separator, lineend)

Comment: it prints nothing? then it's not opening the file

Comment: Yeah it prints nothing, any reason it wouldn't open? The .txt file is in the same director as to where it's pointing

Comment: Hi Jack, can you please explain if you dont mind what symbols = [] does