# How do I select random text on screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How do I select the random text that is after a fixed text using Python? For Example "AWB NO 56454546" where "AWB NO" is fixed text while "56454546" is random text.

Comment: `_, _, awb_no = raw_text.partition("AWB NO ")`

Comment: thanks for the replay Sir, can you please tell me Which module can i use? or can You please write down detailed code? i just started to learn python

Comment: `partition` is a built-in method - you can use it on any string. Try `print("correct horse battery staple".partition("horse"))` and see!

Comment: okay sir now please tell me what do i do if i just want word "battery" that is comming after "horse"

Comment: Note: text is text. Please avoid posting screen shots of text here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `partition` method for this. It's part of the built-in `str` type.

```
>>> help(str.partition)

partition(self, sep, /)
    Partition the string into three parts using the given separator.

    This will search for the separator in the string.  If the separator is found,
    returns a 3-tuple containing the part before the separator, the separator
    itself, and the part after it.

    If the separator is not found, returns a 3-tuple containing the original string
    and two empty strings.
```

If you use `"AWB No: "` as the separator, you'll get back a 3-tuple containing:

- everything before `"AWB No: "` e.g. `"Courier "`
- the separator: `"AWB No: "`
- everything after `"AWB No: "`: `"56454546"`

So you can get that "everything after" part in two ways:

```py
input_str = "Courier AWB No: 56454546"
sep = "AWB No: "
before, sep, after = input_str.partition(sep)
# == "Courier ", "AWB No: ", "56454546"

# or
after = input_str.partition(sep)[2]

# either way: after == "56454546"
```

If there are more words after the number you can get rid of them with `.split()[0]`:

```py
input_str = "Courier AWB No: 56454546 correct horse battery staple"
sep = "AWB No: "
after = input_str.partition(sep)[2]
awb_no = after.split()[0]

# after == "56454546"
```

Or in one line:

```py
input_str = "Courier AWB No: 56454546 correct horse battery staple"
awb_no = input_str.partition("AWB No: ")[2].split()[0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for detaild answer Sir, It means a lot :)

Comment: You are most welcome my friend - good luck!

Comment: Hi Sir, Can you please answer this question? "https://stackoverflow.com/q/71220374/18195529" sorry for the comment here as i don't have any other way to contact You.