# How to change password in script converted to exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I converted a .py file to .exe, now the problem is that script contains passwords and I imported it from another file, but after I converted the file it become the default password.

What if I have to change password? How can I make it import password even after conversion to .exe? Below is the example of the script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
import os
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import tabula
import glob
import Passwords
def cred(id1, pass1, fol_name):

    driver.get(url)
    sleep(2)

    username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
    username_box.send_keys(id1)
    print("Email Id entered")
    sleep(1)

    password_box = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
    password_box.send_keys(pass1)
    print("Password entered")
data = {'myemail@gmail.com':[Passwords.Password1, 'fol']}



for key, value in data.items():
    cred(key, value[0], value[1])
```

Comment: You would have to change whatever is calling `download()` function (or perhaps where that gets the password) — but you have shown or described any of that.

Comment: hello sir, i updated the question, please check it again

Comment: You may be able to search through the .exe file and look for the `data` dictionary with the password in it and change it — at least to something the same length. Overall it would be best to not hardcode the password in the source like that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a config file.
You could use a vault like system : https://www.vaultproject.io/
You can read the password from command line argument.